# Large-scale spherical world in a physics engine

Tags: game-physics, physics-engine, cannon.js

(This question is targeted at [Cannon.js](http://cannonjs.org) (by @schteppe), but hopefully answer(s) will be applicable to other engines for the benefit of others not using Cannon.)

It seems like one strategy for building a huge spherical world in a physics engine is to start with 6 heightmaps forming a cube, and then to warp that cube into a sphere (the "cubic sphere" approach, [see this explanation](http://www.nullpointer.co.uk/content/procedural-planets/)).

So that approach looks fine, and I was about to implement it just because it's what everyone else seems to be doing, but I've got a nagging (and very likely naive) question in the back of my head:

> Why not just generate a (non-rigidbody) spherical surface and use it
>   in the   pre-step of the simulation to provide a reaction force
>   against vertices that fall below that surface? Are there any problems
>   with this approach that make people avoid it and choose the cube
>   sphere approach instead?

Gravity on all objects is allso applied during the pre-step, so it seems like it would just be a matter of checking the object's vertices while I'm at it?

In my particular case the world doesn't need to be high-resolution, and could even be a blocky, minecraft-type world. It also doesn't need any textures or anything like that, if that has some impact on many people choosing the cube sphere approach. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. Could you narrow it down? What are you specifically concerned with?

Comment: Hi @MichaelEricOberlin, I'm just wondering if there's likely to be any problems with this approach (regarding performance or otherwise). It seems like a pretty obvious way of doing it, so I'm guessing since people *don't* do it, there's some fundamental aspect of physics engines in general that I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go the sphere/cube path, you get many things "for free" from the physics engine. It includes stable contacts, friction, collision events etc..

If you implement a "force sphere" that applies force in the normal direction on each penetrating vertex, there are a few obvious things that you will miss:

- No friction: your objects will glide on the planet surface, unless you implement friction yourself (this is difficult to get right without a friction solver).
- "Spongy" contacts: since you're using explicit force calculations and not a contact solver, the contacts will allow larger penetration. (unless you use a large spring coefficient and very small time steps - which is gives bad performance)
- Penetration at ridges: if you want to have some sort of ridge or a sharp mountain peak on your planet, you cannot drop an object straight onto the peak. The peak will penetrate the object where it has no vertices. A physics engine solves this for you with the help of mesh clipping.

Comment: Ahh, so obvious - especially the friction! Thanks so much, and thanks for Cannon :)